# Read a byte from Intptr

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I have an Intptr, and I have a structure of my own which consists of 4 bytes. I want to read 4 bytes from the Intptr into this structure of mine. But i want to fill the 4 bytes in the structure individually. something like

mystruct obj = new mystruct().

obj.byte2 = "read fist byte from Myintptr"
obj.byte1 = "read next byte from MyIntptr"

is this possible ?

one of the ways could be that i read the whole thing into a byte array first using Marshal.copy(), and then do the second step of copying into obj.
But im curious i there is another way

Comment: Do you want to copy bytes from the memory pointed to by the IntPtr or the bytes for the value of the IntPtr?

Comment: Also note that IntPtr is 8 bytes on 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
obj.byte1 = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ip, 0);
obj.byte2 = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(ip, 1);
```

Comment: This copies the bytes from the memory pointed to by the IntPtr. Does the OP want this or the actual 'value' bytes of the IntPtr?

Comment: i want to read the value pointed to by the IntPtr. This looks like its what i want. I will try it and reconfirm that it works (currently stuck somewhere else which is blocking further progress :( )

Answer (score 0):

If the value is in the IntPtr you can cast the ptr to an Int32, and pick the bytes. (Remember that IntPtr will be 8 and not 4 bytes on a 64bit system)

```
IntPtr ptr = ...;
int val = (int)ptr;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(val);
```

or

```
byte b1 = (byte)(val >> 24);
byte b2 = (byte)(val >> 16);
byte b3 = (byte)(val >> 8);
byte b4 = (byte) val;
```

Comment: int val = (int)ptr; will copy the value from the pointer and assign it to a new value type structure.